# check entered values exist or not IF yes prevent saving it Else

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make employees sign in and if they used the button, to save username and time to save multiple times on rows with different of timestamps like this:

[image: Example database]

Now I want to prevent users entering multiple times on their attendance in the database by **making a relationship between `username` and `comedata`** to ensure a user can only sign their attendance once per day.

## Example on my mind

Pseudo code:

```
If username = ComeForm_CGUserName_TextBox.Text
And CGComeDate = ComeForm_CGComeDate_DateTimePicker.Value
And username Is In DB And CGComeDate Is In DataBase
Then
    MsgBox("You have already signed your attendace")
Else
    Insert data into DataBase easy
End If
```

That is the logic I think it needs to follow to prevent multiple entries in the database.

## That's The Full code currently for ComeGo form

```vbs
Public Con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=Euro_SQL_Server;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False")

Public ComeGoDT As New DataTable
Public ComeGoDA As New SqlDataAdapter
Public MyNewComeGoID As Integer

Public Sub Load_ComeGo()
    ComeGoDT.Clear()
    ComeGoDA = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from ComeGo", Con)
    ComeGoDA.Fill(ComeGoDT)
End Sub

Public Sub Code_ComeGo()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select max(CGID) from ComeGo", Con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    If IsDBNull(dt(0)(0)) = True Then
        MyNewComeGoID = 1
    Else
        MyNewComeGoID = dt(0)(0) + 1
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub NewComeGo()
    Code_ComeGo()
    'Auto Generate EmployeesID
    ComeForm_CGID_TextBox.Text = MyNewComeGoID
    'Clearing Fields
    ComeForm_CGComeDate_DateTimePicker.Value = Now.Date
    ComeForm_CGComeTime_DateTimePicker.Value = Now
    ComeForm_CGUserName_TextBox.Text = MangersMainMenu.MangersMainMenu_CurrentUserResult_Label.Text
    ComeForm_CGNotes_TextBox.Text = ""
    'Auto Generate ActionBy From Logged In UserFullName
    ComeForm_ActionBy_TextBox.Text = MangersMainMenu.MangersMainMenu_CurrentUserResult_Label.Text
End Sub

Private Sub ComeForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Load EditComeGo_Form From EURO_DataBase
    Load_ComeGo()
    'Clear Fields
    NewComeGo()
End Sub

Private Sub ComeForm_ComeSign_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComeForm_ComeSign_Button.Click
    'Definition Adding New ComeGo Method
    ComeGoDT.Rows.Add()
    Dim last As Integer = ComeGoDT.Rows.Count - 1
    'Match Each Filed On The DataBase With There Filed On The Table
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGID") = ComeForm_CGID_TextBox.Text
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGDate") = Now.Date
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGTime") = Now
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGUserName") = MangersMainMenu.MangersMainMenu_CurrentUserResult_Label.Text
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGComeDate") = ComeForm_CGComeDate_DateTimePicker.Value
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGComeTime") = ComeForm_CGComeTime_DateTimePicker.Value
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGNotes") = ComeForm_CGNotes_TextBox.Text
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("ActionBy") = MangersMainMenu.MangersMainMenu_CurrentUserResult_Label.Text
    'Definition Saving New Changes Method
    Dim save As New SqlCommandBuilder(ComeGoDA)
    'Refresh ComeGo DataBase Table
    ComeGoDA.Update(ComeGoDT)
    ComeGoDT.AcceptChanges()
    'Show Massage Box
    MsgBox("تم تسجيل حضور الموظف")
    'Reload ComeGo Table With New UpDates
    Load_ComeGo()
    'Start New ComeGo Entery
    NewComeGo()
End Sub
```

## That's The Save Button

```
Private Sub ComeForm_ComeSign_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComeForm_ComeSign_Button.Click
    'Definition Adding New ComeGo Method
    ComeGoDT.Rows.Add()
    Dim last As Integer = ComeGoDT.Rows.Count - 1
    'Match Each Filed On The DataBase With There Filed On The Table
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGID") = ComeForm_CGID_TextBox.Text
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGDate") = Now.Date
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGTime") = Now
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGUserName") = MangersMainMenu.MangersMainMenu_CurrentUserResult_Label.Text
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGComeDate") = ComeForm_CGComeDate_DateTimePicker.Value
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGComeTime") = ComeForm_CGComeTime_DateTimePicker.Value
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGNotes") = ComeForm_CGNotes_TextBox.Text
    ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("ActionBy") = MangersMainMenu.MangersMainMenu_CurrentUserResult_Label.Text
    'Definition Saving New Changes Method
    Dim save As New SqlCommandBuilder(ComeGoDA)
    'Refresh ComeGo DataBase Table
    ComeGoDA.Update(ComeGoDT)
    ComeGoDT.AcceptChanges()
    'Show Massage Box
    MsgBox("تم تسجيل حضور الموظف")
    'Reload ComeGo Table With New UpDates
    Load_ComeGo()
    'Start New ComeGo Entery
    NewComeGo()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I have fixed my problem by adding this code

```
    Dim ComeGoCheck As String
    ComeGoCheck = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ComeGo WHERE CGUserName=@CGUserName AND CGComeDate=@CGComeDate"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(ComeGoCheck, Con)
    Dim query As Integer
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGUserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComeForm_CGUserName_TextBox.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGComeDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ComeForm_CGComeDate_DateTimePicker.Value
    Con.Open()
    query = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Con.Close()
    If query > 0 Then
        MsgBox("لقد تم تسجيل حضور الموظف مسبقا")
        Con.Close()
    Else
    End If
```

## so the full save button code is :

```
Private Sub ComeForm_ComeSign_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComeForm_ComeSign_Button.Click
    Dim ComeGoCheck As String
    ComeGoCheck = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ComeGo WHERE CGUserName=@CGUserName AND CGComeDate=@CGComeDate"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(ComeGoCheck, Con)
    Dim query As Integer
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGUserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComeForm_CGUserName_TextBox.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGComeDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ComeForm_CGComeDate_DateTimePicker.Value
    Con.Open()
    query = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Con.Close()
    If query > 0 Then
        MsgBox("لقد تم تسجيل حضور الموظف مسبقا")
        Con.Close()
    Else
        'Definition Adding New ComeGo Method
        ComeGoDT.Rows.Add()
        Dim last As Integer = ComeGoDT.Rows.Count - 1
        'Match Each Filed On The DataBase With There Filed On The Table
        ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGID") = ComeForm_CGID_TextBox.Text
        ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGDate") = Now.Date
        ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGTime") = Now
        ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGUserName") = MangersMainMenu.MangersMainMenu_CurrentUserResult_Label.Text
        ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGComeDate") = ComeForm_CGComeDate_DateTimePicker.Value
        ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGComeTime") = ComeForm_CGComeTime_DateTimePicker.Value
        ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("CGNotes") = ComeForm_CGNotes_TextBox.Text
        ComeGoDT.Rows(last).Item("ActionBy") = MangersMainMenu.MangersMainMenu_CurrentUserResult_Label.Text
        'Definition Saving New Changes Method
        Dim save As New SqlCommandBuilder(ComeGoDA)
        'Refresh ComeGo DataBase Table
        ComeGoDA.Update(ComeGoDT)
        ComeGoDT.AcceptChanges()
        'Show Massage Box
        MsgBox("تم تسجيل حضور الموظف")
        'Reload ComeGo Table With New UpDates
        Load_ComeGo()
        'Start New ComeGo Entery
        NewComeGo()
        Con.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```